# I want to automatically create a offline backup of git repositories that can be used to restore a failed cloud based repository like Bitbucket

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, backup, clone

I must say that I am fairly new to git which might reflect in my description of the problem. I have research ways to fully make a backup of a repository. Including all branches, tags, everything! I would like to have it as a restore point if my Bitbucket account would be compromised or if my Bitbucket repositories would, for some reason, disappear.

I have tried different things. But I sense I am not fully understanding what is happening and therefore not able to determine which approach is the correct one and why.

There are a lot of questions covering this subject, so I might have missed the obvious answer :-). However I am not able to fully understand if any of them consider all branches or just the one already checked out. If they consider to backup a remote cloud based repo and not a local version of it.

The main things I have explored is a normal git clone followed by a pull --all. I know now that the --all never will pull branches not already checked out. So here I fail to get all existing remote branches.

The second thing I tried was the git clone --mirror which to some extent is a full copy of the remote repository. I fail to understand what I get on disk after just this command. It is super fast and surely not downloading all content. The size is way under even a normal repository when zipped

So I did a three step rocket.

1. git clone -mirror
2. git clone "from the mirror" to "local repo". Then I get a repo with a working tree
3. git pull --all on the local repo created above in hope to get all remote branches as local branches

When done I did a git branch to examine what I got but it still seems like I have more remote branches then local ones.

I apologize if my lack of knowledge confuse things! Which approach shall I use?

I am thinking of one more and that is to do a normal clone. Then get all remote branches to loop them through and do checkout. Would that be a better option?

Comment: you need to understand that git branch is your local branch and git branch -r the remote one, but not asking to the remote but looking on the knowledge of the remote you have in local. When you do a git fetch you retrieve all the remote info, you don"t have to create a local branch for each remote branch

Answer (score 0):

It is easy

**Backup**
To create a backup from the origin bitbucket repository:

1. Visit the Bitbucket site and go to the repository
2. Click the “clone“ button and copy the link
3. Before starting the clone process add `--bare` key for example `git clone --bare git@bitbucket.org:<account-name>/<repo-name>.git`
4. The cloned directory will get .git prefix like `directory-name.git`
   This directory can be stored locally.

**Restore** To restore the local repository to the origin Bitbucket:

1. Visit the Bitbucket site and create a new repository
2. Get the origin link of the new repository `git@bitbucket.org:<account-name>/<new-repository-name>.git`
3. Add the remote origin path `git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:<account-name>/<bitbucket-repo-name>.git` If needed check or remove an old remote path `git remote -v` and `git remote rm origin`
4. Push repository to new origin `git push origin --mirror`

In this case, all data including commits, branches, and all data will be transferred from local storage to the Bitbucket repository.